# No balance after a few days of ETH mining

Tags: nodes, windows, ubuntu, miner

Ive been mining for 1 day and i still have 0 ETH. I am running a GTX 970 and getting 17 MH/s but after running it for a full 24 hours I got nothing. I've been using MinerGate and running it on a Ubuntu Machine. I tried mining ETH on Windows using MinerGate but i still get the same results. I am still a beginner and this is my first time trying to mine ETH.
[image: Screenshot of it]

Comment: try to mine using a pool not in solo mod

Answer (score 1):

According to a [mining profitability calculator](https://minergate.com/calculator/ethereum) provided by MinerGate, you're looking at 0.00006 ETH per hour as of early 2018. This question was asked a long time ago, but it's still relevant. Most pools don't allocate funds directly super fast -- they usually take several hours to allocate your shares. It's a slow process that takes time, in other words. With a lower hashrate, you're going to be getting a lot less of a share than other miners, just because many people do this for a living or have huge networks of miners. Not just one PC.

If you don't try mining with a pool, you're going to be looking at an average of 2,305 days to find a block [according to Etherscan's calculator](https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator) at the current network hashrate. Stick with a pool, and be patient. Remember that this isn't an easy way to make free money -- it's largely a hobby activity for a single person to mine at this point, without getting into specialized hardware and competitive electricity pricing.

Answer (score 1):

The pool you are mining for probably only pays you once you reach a certain minimum, like 0.1 Ethereum. So you may need to mine a bit more until you are actually paid.

You should be able to keep track of how much you have mined in that pool.

On ethermine.org you are able to search for the "Miner Address", you put the public address of your wallet in that box and it should list you the workers mining towards that address and the current unpaid value. (other pools might work differently thou, I'm only familiar with that one and it only pays once you have 0.1 ETH)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply just not have enough hashing power to contribute anything meaningful to the mining network. The total hashing power of the Ethereum network is 40 TH/s.

You may consider mining a different coin that has a lower network hashrate.